# Interpretation of the CI for the standard deviation in random effect models

Tags: confidence-interval, random-effects-model

If the zero belong to the confidence interval for the standard deviation of the random effect models can I conclude that the random effect is not statistically significant?

Comment: Generally speaking if the null value of the parameter falls into say a 95% confidence interval you cannot reject the null hypothesis and the 0.05 level. But the effect is not the standard deviation.  It is the mean.  So you would need more.